# MariaDB: how to overcome TIME type limit

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We have a database hosted by MariaDB. Some tables contain fields of `TIME` type, that has known limitation in value range. Until now the values were compatible with TIME type, but due to new project requirements, some of them meight exceed current limits. I would like to make as few changes as possible. Also, I must preserve the current dataset. Basically, I need a way to change the DB schema (field type in particular) with the least possible impact on the client application. Client application treats TIME fields as pure text, this sholud permit some simplifications. I guess I could change fields' type from `TIME` to `VARCHAR(...)`. Are there  better solutions?

Comment: Store your TIME values as the second amount in some indeger datatype (for example, INT datatype allows to store the time up to ~68 years).

Comment: This is a clean solution by a "formal" point of view, but has the disadvantage that the client application must be changed accordingly. I have just clarified that the client manages TIME fields as pure text.

Comment: if you cannot alter the application then you're correct, you'd alter the datatype to VARCHAR with reasonable length. But you'd only store and retrieve the value, you'd loose the possibility to process this value on the MySQL side. Also you'd loose the value correctness checking and would add according CHECK constraint if you need in such checking.